# why does it say that there is no for loop?

Tags: excel, vba

i am unsure on why this says that there is no for loop when i try to input next row2

```
Sub test4()
    For row2 = 2 To 174
        If IsEmpty("I" & row2) Then
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & row2).Copy _
            Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("R5")
    If IsEmpty("I" & row2) Then Exit For
    Next row2
End Sub
```

Comment: You are missing an `End If` somewhere